# An example of a continuous function such that M

Tags: real-analysis

An example of a continuous function such that $M$ is the maximum of $f$ on $[a,b]$, and that $\{x_i\}$ is a sequence on $[a,b]$ such that $f(x_i)$ converges to $M$ but $\{x_i\}$ is not convergent. I'm confused as to how I can find such a function and what sequence I should be looking for.

Comment: Think about a function that attains its maximum at two different points.

Comment: to make it even easier consider a function that attains it's maximum everywhere.:) The $x_i$ will have to be oscillating in some way since you are on a bounded interval.

Comment: Is there some reason you have for making the problem hard to read?

Comment: Is the constant function out of the question? Another function I can think of is xsin(1\x)

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how to use the proper notation that this site requires.

Comment: The constant function will work. Actually any function which is continuous and attains a maximum of $M$ at two points will work. $x\sin(\frac{1}{x})$ is actually probably not going to work unless $[a,b]$ is symmetric around 0.

Comment: I figured you didn't which is why I fixed it up a little with mathjax. but you seem to have rolled the edits back for some reason.:)

Comment: I believe that i edited again on accident by pushing a button on my phone, sorry about that. And thank you I will think about a function obtaining a maximum at at least two different points.

Comment: No worries.:) I'll see if I can reedit it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for kicks a slightly more trivial solution is $\forall x\in[a,b]\;f(x)=M$, $x_{2i}=a$ and $x_{2i+1}=b$.

Answer (score 1):

Making some of the 
comments explicit,
let
$f(x) = \cos(x)$
on $[0, 2\pi]$
with
$x_{2k} = \frac1{k}$
and
$x_{2k-1} = 2\pi-\frac1{k}$.

Then
$f(x_k) \to 1$
which is the max of $f$.